# I don't know how to solve this summation of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

Here is the question

$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} 2^{x(t-1)}$, where $t$ is a constant

Compare this summation with $Z^c$, where $Z \geq 0$, and specify for what values of $Z$ and $c$, such that $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} 2^{x(t-1)} \gt Z^c$

So the result should be an non-equal equation with no $x$

I try to multiply this series by something but fail to figure out what to be added. Any hint or help is welcome.

Comment: Hint: $a^{bc} = (a^b)^c$ when $a>0$ and $b,c$ are real numbers.

Comment: Do you mean I should write it as $(2^x)^{t-1}$

Comment: Rather $(2^{t-1})^x$. Then it's just a series of the form $\sum_{x=1}^\infty q^x$ for $q=2^{t-1}$. Do you know when it's convergent and to what value?

Comment: it seems to be divergent when abs(q) is greater than 1, and convergent when abs(q) <= 1?

Comment: Almost, when $|q|=1$ then it's divergent, too. Having said that, if $2^{t-1} \ge 1$ then your series is $+\infty$ (so when $t \ge 1$). Can you tell the value of $\sum_{x=1}^\infty (2^{t-1})^x$ for $2^{t-1} < 1$ (so for $t<1$)

Comment: yes! thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome. You can write the answer yourself and accept it, so that this question won't be unanswered

Comment: I will try it! thank you again

Comment: I am sorry, but I found the result still contains x. However my prof said there should be no x in the result. My result is $\frac{q^{x+1} - q}{q-1}$

Comment: It should be $\sum_{x=1}^\infty q^x = \frac{q}{1-q}$ when $|q| < 1$.

Comment: Oh, I know where the problem is. I did not make x goes to infinity